# 404 page not found after deploying Go server on heroku and render

Tags: go, heroku

After deploying my app to Heroku, all I get is a 404 - Page Not Found error. On my local machine it works just fine.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type helloHngResponse struct{
    SlackUsername string `json:"SlackUsername"`
    Backend bool `json:"Backend"`
    Age int `json:"Age"`
    Bio string `json:"Bio"`
}

func helloHng(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    response := helloHngResponse{SlackUsername: "kodeforce98", Backend: true, Age: 24, Bio: "Proud firstborn, Golang Developer, Committed christian, Faithful boyfriend"}
    
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    encoder.Encode(response)
}
```

I feel like the culprit is around here, but i'm lost still.

```
func main(){

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == ""{
        port = "9090"
    }
         
     
    http.HandleFunc("/hellohng", helloHng)
    log.Printf("Server starting on port %v\n", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", port), nil))
}
```

i'm trying to understand why i'm not getting a json output as i do when i run it locally. every help's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Some guesses:

- **you might not have deployed at all** - do you follow the deployment guide here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go?singlepage=true ? If so, do you see the 404 in the server log?
- **you send request without port** - do you send the request to the correct port? `https://polar-inlet-4930.herokuapp.com:9000/hellohng`. You may also change the port to 80 from 9000 in the code, which might help as 80 is default for web requests.